# Find actual logs from log4j

Tags: jsp, logging, intellij-idea, log4j

I have looked at similar posts but am having trouble navigating the waters of log4j. I am just wondering where I need to go to see the actual file created from my logs. I successfully added the correct JAR file as a dependency in my project (I am using IDEA 12). I have imported and set up my logger such as:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ClassDAO.class.getName());
```

And later use it like this:

```
//Log the search
logger.info("Request successful. Size of result set: " + resultSet.size());
```

I have also set up my properties file like this (on the advice of another post) :

```
# Set root logger level and appender name.
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, file

# Specify appenders.
log4j.appender.console = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.file = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender

# Configure console appender.
log4j.appender.console.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{ABSOLUTE} [%t] %-5p %m%n

# Configure file appender.
log4j.appender.file.File = /ClassMonitor/logs/web.log
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{ABSOLUTE} [%t] %-5p %m%n
```

Originally I had

```
log4j.appender.file.File = /webapp/logs.web.log
```

but I wasn't sure if that was implied if that was supposed to be the project name of if that is an actual file path set up already for me.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: know-it-all-comment: Short statements are easier to read like `Result length: ` instead of `Size of result set:`.

Comment: @PeterRader I will keep that in mind, thanks. It's my first production code so I am still trying to find a good balance in things like that.

Comment: Oh your question sounds like a question of a advanced programmer. ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very hard Question! What log-files are actually in use depends on what order of which framework you are using at run-time and at instantiation-time.

I.e.: Log4j or even slf4j can override your apache-log4j-handler at any part of runtime.

I fear: you must try and err for that issue.

Comment: Extremely helpful information @Peter Rader I was not aware of this. This whole stateless business and JSP is messing with my .NET windows forms ways :)

Comment: Btw, if you debug, you can make a breakpoint at the line of interest (i.e. **LOGGER.info("Created Foobar");**) and inspect _LOGGER_ for the concrete _handler_. But be warned, the handler may change later or has been changed.